# EXCEL equivalent for SQL select ... order by

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

Let's suppose I have an excel table:

```
id title value
1  foo   300
2  bar   100
3  baz   100
4  bam   400
```

I want to create a separate excel sheet with id and title of 2 items with smallest values in it.

Is there an excel equivalent for the SQL query like:

```
SELECT id, title FROM table ORDER BY value LIMIT 2;
```

Result:

```
2 baz
3 bar
```

Comment: Do you want to swap the title in the result? `2 bar` from the source becomes `2 baz`?? I'll assume that this is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has several options to achieve that, including

- Advanced Filter
- Power Query (aka Get & Transform)
- formulas

Each approach is different and has its own learning curve.

The Power Query approach:

- load the data into Power Query with the command "from Table/Range" on the data ribbon
- In the Power Query Editor, sort by the value column ascending
- Use the "Keep Rows" command to keep the first two rows
- delete the Value column
- load the query to a new workbook

This approach is (to me) the simplest, since it does not require writing code or formulas and still is dynamic. If the source data changes, simply refresh the query.

[image]